# SoapUI not reading project property

Tags: soapui

I'm trying to use a project property to make up part of a JWT token that I'm passing through for my request.

The project property is: `Name = AuthToken, Value = 12345`.

The following works in the header:

`Header = Authorization, Value = JWT 12345`

But when I try to use property expanison: `Value = JWT ${AuthToken}`

I get an error saying:

```
{
   "statusCode": "InternalServerError",
   "message": "An unknown error has occured. Please try again later.",
   "reason": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax? I've tried a couple of variations based on what I read in the user guides, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to access a **project** property using property expansion is `${#Project#YourPropertyName}`.

So as header value use `JWT ${#Project#AuthToken}` instead of `JWT ${AuthToken}`

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately that's not working either. When I tried that it said ""message": "An error has occurred."

DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Chris It has none sense, if the literal `JWT 12345` it's working; then `JWT ${#Project#AuthToken}` must work... if you've correctly set the `AuthToken` property with the corresponding value... I was used this so many times; maybe it's something wrong with your SOAPUI version? what version are you using?

Comment: @Chris Can you look at the `Raw` tab, and check what is the value for your `AuthToken` header?

Comment: We were making the mistake of putting the name of the project instead of "project" (JWT $(#My_Project#AuthToken). Thanks for the help, all working now

Comment: @Chris yes it's literally `#Project#` not the name of the project, you can check more details [here](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html). Nice to help you `:)`